# pytorch does not save pre-trained model weights loaded and the parts of it in the final model

Tags: save, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I am currently working on pre-trained model on CIFAR-10 on my data, have removed the final fc layer of the model and have appended my own fc layer and  softmax. There are seven networks which each of them are same as pre-trained part and are combined using appended fc layer. The following is pre-trained Network code :

```
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inplanes, expansion=4, growthRate=12, dropRate=0):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        planes = expansion * growthRate
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(inplanes)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inplanes, planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, growthRate, kernel_size=3, 
                               padding=1, bias=False)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.dropRate = dropRate

        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.bn1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        if self.dropRate > 0:
            out = F.dropout(out, p=self.dropRate, training=self.training)

        out = torch.cat((x, out), 1)

        return out


class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inplanes, expansion=1, growthRate=12, dropRate=0):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        planes = expansion * growthRate
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(inplanes)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inplanes, growthRate, kernel_size=3, 
                               padding=1, bias=False)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.dropRate = dropRate

        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.bn1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        if self.dropRate > 0:
            out = F.dropout(out, p=self.dropRate, training=self.training)

        out = torch.cat((x, out), 1)

        return out


class Transition(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inplanes, outplanes):
        super(Transition, self).__init__()
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(inplanes)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(inplanes, outplanes, kernel_size=1,
                               bias=False)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.bn1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 2)
        return out


class DenseNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, depth = 22, block = Bottleneck, 
        dropRate = 0, num_classes = 10, growthRate = 12, compressionRate = 2):
        super(DenseNet, self).__init__()

        assert (depth - 4) % 3 == 0, 'depth should be 3n+4'
        n = (depth - 4) / 3 if block == BasicBlock else (depth - 4) // 6

        self.growthRate = growthRate
        self.dropRate = dropRate

        # self.inplanes is a global variable used across multiple
        # helper functions
        self.inplanes = growthRate * 2 
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, self.inplanes, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1,
                               bias = False)
        self.dense1 = self._make_denseblock(block, n)
        self.trans1 = self._make_transition(compressionRate)
        self.dense2 = self._make_denseblock(block, n)
        self.trans2 = self._make_transition(compressionRate)
        self.dense3 = self._make_denseblock(block, n)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.inplanes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(8)
        #self.fc = nn.Linear(self.inplanes, num_classes)

        # Weight initialization
#         for m in self.modules():
#             if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
#                 n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
#                 m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
#             elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
#                 m.weight.data.fill_(1)
#                 m.bias.data.zero_()


    def _make_denseblock(self, block, blocks):
        layers = []
        for i in range(blocks):
            # Currently we fix the expansion ratio as the default value
            layers.append(block(self.inplanes, growthRate = self.growthRate, dropRate=self.dropRate))
            self.inplanes += self.growthRate

        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def _make_transition(self, compressionRate):
        inplanes = self.inplanes
        outplanes = int(math.floor(self.inplanes // compressionRate))
        self.inplanes = outplanes
        return Transition(inplanes, outplanes)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)

        x = self.trans1(self.dense1(x)) 
        x = self.trans2(self.dense2(x)) 
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        x = self.avgpool(x)
        #x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        #x = self.fc(x)

        return x
    
    
    def getParams(self, paramName):
        if paramName == 'inplanes':
            return self.inplanes
        elif paramName == 'growthRate':
            return self.growthRate
        elif paramName == 'dropRate':
            return self.dropRate
        
def densenet(**kwargs):
    """
    Constructs a DenseNet model.
    """
    return DenseNet(**kwargs)
```

and the next following is my code:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self,pretrained_dict, num_classes = 6, num_channels = 7, 
                 expansion = 4, depth = 100, growthRate = 12, dropRate = 0):
        
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_channels = num_channels
        
        # creating 7 channels networks 
        self.channels_dnsnets = []
        
        for ch in range(self.num_channels):
#             print(ch)
            
            d = densenet(depth = depth)
            d_dict = d.state_dict()
            
            # 1. filter out unnecessary keys
            pretrained_dict2 = {k[7:]: v for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k[7:] in d_dict}
#             print('d_dict_keys :')
#             print(d_dict.keys())
#             print('*'*50)
#             print('pretrained_dict2.keys:')
#             print(pretrained_dict2.keys())
#             print('*'*50)
            
            # 2. overwrite entries in the existing state dict
            d_dict.update(pretrained_dict2) 
            
            # 3. load the new state dict
            d.load_state_dict(pretrained_dict2)
            
            # freeze the layers of densenet
            for param in d.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
                
            self.channels_dnsnets.append(d)
            
        self.inplanes = self.channels_dnsnets[0].getParams(paramName = 'inplanes')
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.inplanes * self.num_channels, num_classes)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim = 1)
        
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        batch_size, channels, ht, wd, in_channels = x.shape
        x = np.reshape(x,(batch_size,channels,in_channels,ht,wd))

        out = []
    
        for num in range(self.num_channels):
            temp_out = self.channels_dnsnets[0](x[:,num,:])
            temp_out = temp_out.view(temp_out.size(0),-1)
#             print(temp_out.shape)
#             print('*' * 50)
            out.append(temp_out)
        
        out = torch.stack(out,dim = 1)
#         print(out.shape)
        out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = self.softmax(out)
        return out
```

I am setting the optimizer as :

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr = lr, 
                                 betas = (0.9, 0.999), eps = 1e-08, weight_decay = wd, amsgrad = False)
```

However, whenever I save the model the list of densenets and their weights are not saved and only fc layer and softmax layer weights are saved. Is there anything problematic with code? I am new to pytorch.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `self.channels_dnsnets` is just a `list` and will not be part of the `state_dict`. Only `self.fc` and `self.softmax` will be registered into the `Module`. The simplest change would be to define it like this:

```py
self.channels_dnsnets = nn.ModuleList()
```

Comment: I too realised the same ! thank you for your answer :)